# Gateway vs Agent OpenTelemetry collector deployment on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry

there is 2 ways to deploy OpenTelemetry collector on Kubernetes
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/deployment/
Agent and Gateway

my question is when deploying OpenTelemetry collector as a deamonset
why we still need the Agent ?
https://www.aspecto.io/blog/opentelemetry-collector-guide/
[agent mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTtgL.png)

and also is it good approach to deploy OpenTelemetry as a deamonset without the Agent ?

Answer (score 2):

Before I get to the core of your question, note that the agent/gateway modes are not Kubernetes specific. This pattern is equally valid and applicable in case you're running your microservices on, say, virtual machines or ECS.

Now, let's dive deeper into why there are cases where it makes sense to use the OpenTelemetry collector in agent/gateway mode. At its core, it's about separation of concerns, enabling different teams to focus on things they care about.

The *agent mode* means running an OpenTelemetry collector "close" to the workload. In the context of Kubernetes, this could be a sidecar (another  container running the collector in the app pod), you could run a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) per namespace, and indeed you could run the collector as a DaemonSet. No matter how you run these collectors, the expectation would be that the dev or product team owns the collector (config) and with it decides what receivers are needed for workloads. For example, one team needs a [Prometheus receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/prometheusreceiver), another team needs a [Statsd receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/statsdreceiver) for their app. We get back to the outbound (exporter) side of the collector in a moment.

The *gateway mode* means a central (standalone) operation of the collector, typically owned by the platform team, enabling them to:

1. Centrally enforce policies such as filtering sensitive log items, making sampling decisions for traces, dropping certain metrics, and so forth.
2. Manage permissions and credentials in a central place. For example, in order to ingest metrics using the [Prometheus Remote Write exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusremotewriteexporter) into Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus, the collector needs to use an [IAM role with a specific IAM policy attached](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-onboard-ingest-metrics-OpenTelemetry.html). The same applies for OTLP exporters, requiring you to provide an API key.
3. Scale the collector: either by running a bunch of OpenTelemetry collectors behind a loadbalancer and scale them horizontally or by vertically scaling a single collector instance. Through managing the collector scaling, the platform team can ensure that all signals (traces, metrics, logs) are reliable delivered to the backend destinations.

Now we get back to the communication between agents and gateway: this is done via the [OpenTelemetry Protocol (OTLP)](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/reference/specification/protocol/otlp/). That is, using the OTLP exporter on the agent side and the OTLP receiver on the gateway side, which further simplifies both the task on the side of the dev/product teams and the platform team, providing for a secure and performant telemetry data transfer.

Comment: thank you. I summarises our deployment decision here:https://idanreuven.wordpress.com/2022/10/13/opentelemetry-deployment-on-kubernetes-agent-or-gateway/